# Identify text areas on a Talmud page

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr, image-segmentation

I have a Talmud page like these:
[image]
[image]
And I want to find the text areas with `opencv` to get such a result, that each text will be on its own like this:

[image]

In the attached image, each area is marked in a different color, and text has a number, what is important is to identify the area belonging to each text, and differentiate it from the area belonging to another text, the numerical order does not matter.

Doing it with the eyes is really easy, according to the white stripes that pass between the texts, but I tried to do it with `opencv` and I could not.

In the following code I try to catch all the letters and turn them into black rectangles,
Then magnify each rectangle to meet with a neighboring rectangle,
And so the whole area of the text will be black, and between the texts there will be a clear white stripe.

I do not know how to proceed, and if it is a good approach.

```
public List<Rectangle> getRects(Mat grayImg)
{
    BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
    blobCounter.ObjectsOrder = ObjectsOrder.None;
    blobCounter.ProcessImage(grayImg);
    IEnumerable<Blob> blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();

    var blackBlobs = grayImg.Clone;
    foreach (var b in blobs)
        blackBlobs.Rectangle(b.Rectangle.ToCvRect, Scalar.Black, -1);

    var widths = blobs.Select(X => X.Rectangle.Width).ToList;
    widths.Sort();
    var median = widths(widths.Count / (double)2);

    Mat erodet = new Mat();
    Cv2.Erode(grayImg, erodet, null, iterations: median);

    using (Window win = new Window())
    {
        win.ShowImage(erodet);
        win.WaitKey();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

**Additional clarification:**

As you can see in the previous image, the text areas are not rectangular,
But these areas can be described as a collection of rectangles of different sizes arranged in a pile, one on top of the other.

Note that when two rectangles belong to the same text, do not arrange one rectangle next to another rectangle, but only one above the other.

What I am trying to achieve is a collection of these rectangles and knowing each rectangle to which text it belongs.

An answer can be in any programming language, especially in `C++` `Python` and `C#`

Comment: I wouldn't look for rectangles on the first pass, I'd look for white lines. Look up how to do optical filtering and find a 1-dimensional filter that recognizes the text blocks as grey, but is able to pick up the white space. Scan the page in each direction (say, at a frequency of 3 or 4 scans per character height) and build a model of grey blobs separated by white space. It will require a little trial and error to get right. If the pages are not well aligned (like you show), it will be much harder. If so, you may first want to do something to figure out the alignment and then pre-rotate things

Comment: You can try morphological operation erode. 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(19,8))
out = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this task can be done mostly using [morphological operations](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#morphological-operations).
It is easier to show the concept in [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab), but [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) has equivalent operations.

We start with a rough estimation of the size of the gap between the different sections of the page. Looking at your example, the gap is about 1% of the page's height.

```matlab
img = im2single(rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoV5x.jpg')));  % read the image into 1ch gray scale image in range [0, 1]
gap = ceil(size(img,1) * 0.01);  % gap estimation
```

First, we would like to use image [dilation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#dilation) to create a mask where all words in the same section are connected to each other:

```matlab
d1 = imdilate(img < 0.5, ones(gap));
```

Resulting with:
[image]

(If it wasn't for the annoying words from the next page the printer adds at the bottom of each section we would have been done...)

There are some large gaps the dilation did not fill, we can use [`floodfill`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=floodfill#floodfill) to complete them:

```matlab
f = imfill(d1, 'holes');
```

Now we have full masks for the text regions:
[image]

Using [erosion](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#erosion) to cut between the different sections:

```matlab
e = imerode(f, ones(1, 5*gap));  % erosion only horizontally
```

Resulting with correct partition, although too thinned:
[image]

Dilating back

```matlab
d2 = imdilate(e, ones(1, 5*gap));
```

gives this binary mask:
[image]

You can now simply look at the [connected components](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaedef8c7340499ca391d459122e51bef5) of this binary mask:
[image]

I hope this will count as a "Daf Yomi" for me...

---

**Update:**
The next step - going from segments to rectangular polygons requires some geometrical operations, I'll outline the approach here and leave the implementation details to you.
Eventually, we want a bounding [*polygon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon) for each segment, with the basic polygon being the rectangle bounding box of the segment. You'll have to implement this "polygon" class. A crucial method of this class is "polygon subtraction" - that is `poly_result = poly_a - poly_b` create a new polygon `poly_result` which is `poly_a` minus the intersection between `poly_a` and `poly_b`.

Here's the algorithm:

1. For each segment compute it's bounding box, the area of the bounding box and the actual number of pixels in the segment.
   Init the polygon of each segment to its bounding box.
2. Sort the segments based on the ratio between the number of pixels and the bounding box area in a descending order.
3. For each segment in a descending order:
   subtract all previous polygons from this segment's.

You should get something like this:

[image: enter image description]
And for the second image:
[image: enter image description]

Comment: Thank you, how do you convert non-rectangular areas to several rectangles that will cover the area like a pile, and as I explained in the question?

Comment: Thank you very much, I do not know how to mess with matlab, please write a code that works and can be run in Python, so I can check that everything works properly for me too. Thanks.

Comment: @googledev stackoverflow is not for "write a code for me" but rather "help me write my own code". This answer outlines an algorithm step-by-step and also contains references to opencv functions that implements the operation that each step outputs. You should be able to take it from here. I gave you the Talmud + Rashi, you need to do Tosfot on your own.

Comment: Note, there are some words that do not appear after erotion.

Comment: @googledev I know. this is not a finalize algorithm - there are many "edge cases" that needs to be solved. but it's a good starting point. You might to treat the title line in a different way,

Comment: My concern is that these are not edge cases, and that there are many such cases and a different approach will be needed to solve this problem.

Comment: @googledev As explained in the answer, the algorithm is based on using morphological operation to form a "solid" mask for each text region. to that end we estimate the size of gaps between lines and words _within_ a "block" of text. The title line clearly does not share the same "statistics" - it has fewer words, widely spaced and with larger fonts. Therefore, the title line, that does not "adhere" to the rules of the rest of the page, will need to be treated separately. If there are other parts of the page that has significantly different behavior - then you are right.

Comment: @Shai What does the (img <0.5 ) part of your code does in this line```d1 = imdilate(img < 0.5, ones(gap));``` ? I am using python opencv and I guess it is to resize the image.

Comment: @Shashiwadana it's not resizing, it's thresholding

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you are first trying to perform a layout analysis to extract the regions of interest. This is an area of research, not very well known, but with some good results for the problem. If you are not determined to solve this problem using `opencv`, I recommend you look into Optical Layout Recognition (OLR). The [LAREX](https://github.com/OCR4all/LAREX) open-source tool is an excellent starting point.